# Add an image to a field using a url Discord PY

Tags: python, discord.py

So basically I have this code:

```
for x in STITEMS:
    counter+=1
    embedVar.add_field(name=f"Starting item #{counter}",url=x['src'],inline=True)
```

I want to add an image to a field using a url, but it does not work

```
TypeError: add_field() got an unexpected keyword argument 'url'
```

Any ideas on how to make it work? Is it even possible, or should I convert these images to emojis and use it that way?

Comment: The error clearly state that `embedVar.add_field()` does not expect the argument `url`, so it's likely to have a problem there. What exactly is `embedVar`? Please, provide some more code so we can understand better and test ourself. Try to look at [how to create a mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that add_field doesn't take the argument 'url'. You need to use the .set_image method to add an image to an embed. In your case,

```
embedVar.set_image(url = 'your URL here')
```

Comment: Is there a way to add multiple images?